# domstyle.set not working in dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have a strange problem in Dojo. My domStyle.set is not working as intended. I am assuming ofcourse that it is the right way of setting a style to a dom node.

Here is the html snippet that describes the dom node.

```
<div class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" style="display: table-cell; min-   height:70%;" data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
      <div style="display: table; width:100%; height: 100%">
            <div style="display: table-row">
                   <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">
                         <div id="da" name="da" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;width:300px;height:250px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The da node is the drawing area node. I am attempting to change the size of the drawing area node with the code in this javascript file. I have setup a debug point and it is coming into the domStyle.set location. So , its not a case of my absolutely stupidity :)

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare','../util/XMLLoader',"dojo/query",'dojo/_base/lang',
    'dijit/registry','dojo/on',"dojo/dom-style", 'dojo/domReady!'], function (declare,XMLLoader,query,lang,registry,on,domStyle) {

return declare(null, {
    setup : function(){
        var loader = new XMLLoader();
        loader.load("example.xml","editor");
        this.resizeDrawingArea();
        var selector = query("#sizeSelect")[0];
        on(selector,"change",lang.hitch(this,"resizeDrawingArea"));
        //
    },
    resizeDrawingArea : function (evt){
        var drawArea = query("#da");
        var selector = query("#sizeSelect")[0];
        switch(selector.value)
        {
            case "MPU":
                //drawArea.style("width","300px","height","250px");
                domStyle.set(drawArea,"width","300px");
                break;
            case "LDR":
                domStyle.set(drawArea,"width","728px");
                break;
            case "SKY":
                break;
            case "MSTR":
                break;
            case "LMPU":
                break;
            case "STD":
                break;
            case "WSKY":
                break;
            case "SQR":
                break;
            case "SSQR":
                break;
        }
    }


    });
});
```

My idea is to use a "select" list to swap between the different sizes. It somehow doesnt seem to work as easily as expected.

Is there something I am doing wrong here? I would be glad to furnish more information if need be. Using dojo 1.7.2 here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dojo.query doesn't return dom node itself even if you specify node id like '#da'. It always returns NodeList.
So you have to change your code like below.

```
  domStyle.set(drawArea[0],"width","300px");
```

Or you can use dojo.byId to access dom node directly instead of using dojo.query.

Answer (score 0):

NodeList extends itself with chainable domClass domStyle etc. As a sideeffect you can apply styles or add/remove classes and so on to all nodes in the result in one line

```
dojo.query("selector", beneathThisNode).style( { width: '300px' } );
```

or

```
dojo.query("selector").forEach(function(node) { domStyle.set(node, "width", "300px"): } )
```

or even only on some, until a conditional is not met

```
dojo.query("selector").some(function(node) { 
  if( ! dojo.attr(node, "lookfor"))
    return false;
  domStyle.set(node, "width", "300px"): 
} )
```